# JFrame not displaying, nothing is displaying

Tags: java, jframe

I have no idea why my `JFrame` isn't displaying and its really bugging me and i feel like I'm missing something easy and I'm just not seeing it. So any help would be awesome!

here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.*;

public class Lorenzo_ChatClient_class extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Lorenzo_ChatClient_class frame = new Lorenzo_ChatClient_class();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/** Create the frame. */
public Lorenzo_ChatClient_class() {
    //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(100,100);

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(0, 244, 450, 34);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Send");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(351, 6, 99, 122);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Quit");
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(351, 124, 99, 122);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

    JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_1.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("EditorPane.border"));
    textArea_1.setBounds(6, 6, 345, 240);
    contentPane.add(textArea_1);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);


}
}
```

Comment: You can simplify your main method to this line: `EventQueue.invokateLater(() -> new Lorenzo_ChatClient_class().setVisible(true));`

Comment: `JFrame frame = new JFrame();frame.setSize(100,100);` This frame? the one you haven't added to your contentPane? Or the textarea you haven't added?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I read over your code too quickly, because you do have Lorenzo_ChatClient_class extending JFrame. That changes the solution drastically.

I think your main method looks fine. You shouldn't be calling overridable methods in a constructor; it leads to a lot of bugs. Try changing the code to this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class Lorenzo_ChatClient_class extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Lorenzo_ChatClient_class frame = new Lorenzo_ChatClient_class();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Lorenzo_ChatClient_class() {
    super();
    frameSetup();
    setVisible(true); // or just keep it in your main method
}

private void frameSetup() {
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    this.setSize(100, 100);
    this.contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(0, 244, 450, 34);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Send");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(351, 6, 99, 122);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Quit");
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(351, 124, 99, 122);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

    JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_1.setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("EditorPane.border"));
    textArea_1.setBounds(6, 6, 345, 240);
    contentPane.add(textArea_1);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setColumns(10);
    }
}
```

I just tried it out and this works for me, although it's a small frame. Not sure what your reasoning for having `setbounds(100, 100, 450, 300)` followed immediately by `setSize(100,100)`. You're setting the size to 450x300, and then immediately resetting the size to 100x100. I deleted the `setSize(100, 100)` line and the JFrame opened up a lot nicer.

Comment: I edited my answer because I read over your code too quickly. You were extending JFrame correctly, but your constructor was a bit wonky. I moved most of the code into a setup method and the code seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your main method ,

```
Lorenzo_ChatClient_class frame = new Lorenzo_ChatClient_class();
```

In your constructor,

```
setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(100,100);

You have taken class reference and JFrame names are same "frame".
```